# Combinatorics pairs problem

Tags: combinatorics

I want to solve the following problem. Suppose I have two balls in a bag, one red (R) and one blue (B), and a coin. I extract 3 draws from the balls' bag with replacement and toss the coin another 3 times. The realizations of this experiment give pairs such as (B,H);(B,T);(R,H). Each realized pair consists on a color and a tail/head. Then, suppose that there is an agent who observes the 3 pairs of realizations and who **is forced to report only one**. The tricky thing is that the agent has some preferences over what to show. They are defined as follows:

-She **cannot** lie about the color of a ball.

-She **can** lie about the realization of the coin and will do so following some preferences: (B,H)>(B,T)>(R,T)>(R,H).

According to this, the agent will always report (B,H) when there is (at least) one blue ball available. On the other hand, she will never say (R,H) and we will only see (R,T) when she is maximally constrained.

I want to derive a formula to calculate the number of states in which she will lie. For the case N=3 and k=1 (3 draws and 1 report), I came with the following:

$$
\#(lying\_set) \equiv 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{N}\binom{N}{j}2^{N-j}
$$

Where the 1 counts the state (R,H);(R,H);(R,H) and the summation accounts for all the states with $j$ (B,T) pairs.

Is this correct? Is there a way to generalize this for any $k$ and $N$ ?

**Edit: Reports for $k>1$**

Preferences remain unchanged. Therefore, the agent always fills the $k$ with (B,H) when possible. If this is not possible, she will be filling the gaps according to her preferences.

Here is an example of reports given a realization for $k=2,N=3$:

**(R,H);(R,H);(B,T) -----> (B,H);(R;T)**

**(R,H);(R,T);(B,T) -----> (B,H);(R;T)**

(B,H);(R,H);(B,H) -----> (B,H);(B;H)

(R,H);(R,T);(R,T) -----> (R,T);(R;T)

She is lying on bold states and telling the truth on the unbolded ones.

My intuition is to reverse the problem and think about states in which the agent will be constrained. However, I have some problems deriving a general formula for those as I care about the pairs of balls and tosses matching. For instance, for the case $N=3,k=2$,(i.e she is forced to tell 2 under the same preferences as above),  we know the agent will lie in the cases where there is none of the following:

-(B,H);(B,H);(B,)

-(R,T);(R,T);(R,)

-(B,H);(R,T);(B,)

-...

Carefully counting the rest of the combinations gives me 28 states where she will not lie.

Comment: You did not specify how reports are formed for $k>1$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: What is right???

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your comment. I edit the question now to be more precise

Comment: Do you understand correctly that once an event is reported the true corresponding event is removed and procedure repeats $k-1$ times?

Comment: Yes, indeed. That is true given a realization. You can think of a sequential decision problem. Given a draw, the agent reports according to her preferences. Then that report is "wasted" (removed as you mention), and she continues with the rest of the events in the realization. My goal is to count the total number of states in which the report does not match (i.e. is not a subset) the realization. I can me more explicit with an example if that's not clear. Let me know :)

Comment: Given a draw of $N$ pairs, the agent reports $k$ pairs according to her preferences. Once she reports one, then that pair is "wasted" (removed as you mention), and she continues with the rest of the $k-1$ reports.
Then, for instance, for (R,H);(R,H);(B,T), she starts with the preferred one B, and, as she can lie, makes a (B,H). Now she faces (R,H);(R,H). Both are equally disliked, she cannot lie about R so will finish her report with an (R,T). Final report: (B,H);(R;T) 
None of them is on the original realization thus she is lying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n_x$ be the number of event $x$ were $x\in\{BH,BT,RT,RH\}$.

The agent will tell true in two cases:
$$\begin{align}
1)\quad& n_{BH}\ge k\\
2)\quad& n_{BT}=0\ \&\ n_{BH}+n_{RT}\ge k
\end{align}$$
The number of combinations in both cases is easy to compute:
$$\begin{align}
1)\quad& N_1=\sum_{i=k}^n\binom ni 3^{n-i}\\
2)\quad& N_2=\sum_{i=k}^n\binom ni 2^i
\end{align}$$

In this way we however doubly counted the events with both $n_{BT}=0$ and  $n_{BH}\ge k$. The number of such events is:
$$
N_{12}=\sum_{i=k}^n\binom ni 2^{n-i}.
$$

Thus the number of combinations with true reports reads:
$$
N=N_1+N_2-N_{12}=\sum_{i=k}^n\binom ni \left[3^{n-i}+2^i-2^{n-i}\right]
$$

For $n=3$, $k=2$ this gives $N=23$ which differs from your result but agrees with my hand-check.